# What's wrong with my code in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem and I am hoping you could help me.

This is the error I get when I want to open my wordpress page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /web/WebSites/d/v/i/e/viennaphotobookfestival.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/social_icons.php on line 52

I don't know what's wrong in the codes, can you help me?
Thanks in advance!

```
<ul class="et-social-icons">

<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_facebook_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_facebook_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Facebook', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_twitter_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_google_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-google-plus">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_google_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Google', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="et-social-icons">

<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_facebook_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_facebook_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Facebook', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_twitter_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_google_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-google-plus">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_google_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Google', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_rss_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
    <li class="et-social-icon et-social-rss-plus">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( et_get_option( 'divi_rss_url', '#' ) ); ?>" class="icon">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'rss', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Start by showing us which is line **52** of the **51** line script

Comment: Well, you're missing an `endif` on the third `if`-statement?

Comment: I think your 21 first lines (until `<ul class="et-social-icons">` excluded) are there because of a wrong copy-paste.